# How can I check if a Playstation ID name exists?

Tags: php, playstation

I own a website that generates Playstation ID names, how can I show the user if that name is already taken or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I may have not access to check Sony's databases but they do and they are so nice to show me the results.

This is the url using the GET method (change the onlineId value) :

```
https://secure.us.playstation.com/playstation/psn/profile/public/userData?onlineId=Foo&_=1396604840999
```

You also need to use this url as the referrer:

```
https://secure.us.playstation.com/logged-in/trophies/public-trophies/
```

Basically this will show `{}` if the user doesn't have a PSN ID. However this will still show empty if the user isn't registered to the PSN but is registered to other Sony services, meaning that that username can't be used.

This is the example result for my account:

```
    {
    "handle":"tecya_115",
    "avatarUrl":"//static-resource.np.community.playstation.net/avatar_m/3RD/30002_m.png",
    "isPlusUser":"0",
    "curLevel":"5",
    "progress":"0",
    "trophies":{
               "bronze":"118",
               "gold":"3",
               "platinum":"0",
               "silver":"12"
               },
    "totalLevel":""
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You cant. You dont have access to check Sony's databases...